# Anyone who used WSDL with .NET?

Tags: map, wsdl

How do we use mapping in the .NET using the Enterprise WSDL? I have an object, for me to update the records in it, I need to check if a particular field inside another object related to it is true or false. Instead of using separate `foreach` to loop for each object. I'll be using a `map`, to map the two objects. How am I able to do that?

**Code Snippets:**

```
foreach (var record in queryResult.records)
{
    Opportunity sfdcOpp = (Opportunity)record; //pull records

    if (pendingList != null) //paramenter of a method.
    {
        foreach (InvoiceDetail invoiceDetail in pendingList) //this .NET Object
        {

            if (invoiceDetail.ProjectName == sfdcOpp.Project_Code__c)
            {
                 DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Today;
                 Opportunity updateOpp = new Opportunity();

                 //I want to use this in a map rather than to use foreach 
                 //and loop each record.
                 Object_related_to_Opportunity obList = new Object_related_to_Opportunity; 

                 if(currentDate.Month == invoiceDetail.InvoiceDate.Month
                    && currentDate.Year == invoiceDetail.InvoiceDate.Year)
                 {
                     //Code here where I'm going to use both Objects to update a record
                 }
```

Comment: can you post some code, its hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @superfell I provided you a sample code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, I can use `Dictionary<string, Object2> objList = new Dictionary<string, Object2>();` and `objList.TryGetValue(obj1.Id, out obj2)`. :) since Dictionary is similar to Map in salesforce. It's a key/value pair.